# holes in arrays vs. undefined and the map function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I understand that [`map` is not called on undefined indexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on arrays and I appreciate that an undefined index is different from an array index explicitly assigned the 'undefined' value (it is, isn't it?). Yet, how is one supposed to distinguish between holes in an array and `undefined` values?

The below code:

*foo.js*

```
var arr = [,,undefined,,,,3,,,4];
console.log("A hole the same as undefined? "+(arr[0]===undefined?"yes":"no"));
var _ignored = arr.map(function(x) {console.log("f called on ["+x+"]");});
```

... produces when running:

```
$ node foo.js 
A hole the same as undefined? yes
f called on [undefined]
f called on [3]
f called on [4]
```

... similar results are to be had when replacing `map` with `forEach`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `in` operator tells you if an index has been actually assigned to:

```js
a = []
a[5] = window.foo

document.write(a[4] + "<br>")
document.write(a[5] + "<br>")

document.write((4 in a) + "<br>")
document.write((5 in a) + "<br>")
```

Javascript arrays are actually objects with a special `length` property, and array indexes are just property names (in fact, they are even strings, not numbers, internally). So the above definition is equivalent to:

```
a = {
  5: window.foo,
  length: 6
}
```

Therefore, all object functionality related to keys (like `in`, `hasOwnProperty`, `Object.keys`) work for array indexes as well.

`forEach` and other iteration methods [work by iterating from 0 to length-1 and checking if n-th index is actually present in the argument](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18), they don't "know" if the argument is actually an array or just a generic object:

```js
a = {1:'one', 5:'five', length:100};

[].forEach.call(a, function(x) {
  document.write(x)
});
```

Comment: I gather from the answer that `forEach`, `map` etc. methods are not invoked on holes but may be invoked on indexes assigned the `undefined` value and there's no idiomatic way to require that they not be invoked on the latter cases; I would have to make the check inside the function passed as argument to `forEach` or `map`.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: yes, that's correct. `forEach` doesn't care what is assigned to your indexes, the only that matters is if the index was defined at some point.

Answer (score -2):

What you call a "hole" is not exactly a hole:

```
var a = [,,,,,,,,,,];
a.length;  // 10
var n, k;
n=0; for (k in a){if (a.hasOwnProperty(k)){++n;}else{break;}};
n; // 10 : a has 10 own properties, all SET to undefined
```

Now delete all properties, and recount

```
while (n--) delete a[n];
for (k in a){if (a.hasOwnProperty(k)){++n;}else{break;}};
n; // 0
a.length; // 10 : a is identical to Array(10), empty array of length 10
```

To get an array with holes you can either delete properties by hand, or start with Array(N) and fill some indices with values, or use push/splice but not methods that return an array. For instance:

```
Array(2).concat([void(0)]).concat(Array(3)).concat([3]).concat(Array(2)).concat([4]);
```

reproduces exactly your original array (it has length 10 and 10 own properties), althought the first summand (Array(2)) has none.

---

**EDIT** : The above was tested in ExtendScript and is not true in recent browsers (see comments). Tested afterwards in Firefox and [,,,,,,] indeed has no own property...

Comment: You will want to rerun your first snippet. Those *are* holes, the `n` count is `0` not `10`. Or what non-ES5 engine were you using?

Comment: Btw, there's no reason to have that `break` in your loop. It might lead to wrong (too small) results.

Comment: Thanks for testing, i'm actually in ExtendScript (Adobe), which is equipped with ...ES3, and rerunning it invariably gives the same answer : 0. The break is ok since own properties are parsed first.

Comment: Yes, it gives `0`, but your comment states: `n; // 10 : a has 10 own properties, all SET to undefined`. Please fix.

Comment: Well my last comment has a missprint: it always gives 10. As many own properties as entries, although they are undefined. That was the point of my post but it might be a feature of ExtendScript, i didnt test in a browser.